# Chrome Extension Force Install on Chrome Enterprise

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, group-policy

I'm getting the following error when enrolling devices into our Chrome Managed browsers:

> This policy is working as intended but a conflicting value is set elsewhere and is overridden by this policy. Value (conflict) ["bfogiafebfohielmmehodmfbbebbbpei;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx"] Cloud Machine Mandatory

I'm using a PowerShell script to add the Enrol Token to the device, and the devices are part of AD domain as well.

I tried to force the new policies update and tried to locate the issue but couldn't locate the conflicting policy.